# MONGODB: Convert SQL Union query

Tags: mysql, mongodb, union

I'm converting from MySql to MongoDB. Now I can't find a replace for this query:

```
(SELECT id, name, (score_kills - score_deaths) AS points FROM player ORDER BY points DESC LIMIT 10)
UNION
(SELECT id, name, (score_kills - score_deaths) AS points FROM player ORDER BY points ASC LIMIT 10);
```

This selects the 10 best and worst players sorted by the calculated field `points`.
Can anyone help me with this?

The documents in player in MongoDB look like this:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("1234567890"),
    name: "foo",
    score_kills: 321,
    score_deaths: 43
}
```

Comment: Well basically you don't. You do two queries and get the results from each. I would question the practicality of your particular case as you seem to be trying to combine a result that seems to be naturally separated. Let me ask you, "From your combined result, how do you determine which ones where your top 10"?" What was that? List the first 10 did you say? Wouldn't you just have that from two queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with aggregation framework.  It won't be particularly efficient to do it in one query, so you should probably just do the same thing that you're doing in SQL which is running two queries - the only difference is that MongoDB won't "union" them for you, and you'll have to do it in the application.

The two aggregation queries would be:

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
        {$project:{name:1, points:{$subtract:["$score_kills","$score_deaths"]}}},
        {$sort:{points:-1}},
        {$limit:10}
]);
```

This would give you the top 10.  To get the bottom 10 you would do the same thing but sort by `{points:1}` which will leave you with bottom 10.

Comment: It's possible to do this with one complicated ugly aggregation, though it will be likely much less efficient than running the two faster ones.

Comment: And another occurrence of the topN problem. This would be the efficient approach and there **does** seem to be a natural seperation between the two sets of results where it does not seem natural to combine them.

Comment: @NeilLunn if you check the Jira ticket for this, you'll see that this is a pretty old request.  It turns out implementing it is simple, the hard part is to have consistent (and sensible) syntax for it.

Comment: I have. Up-voted and followed even. What seems to be needed is a forum to hash this out and help it through triage.

Comment: you're welcome to make comments on the ticket itself - any user  constructive input is taken into account when considering what to implement and how.

Comment: That was what I head in mind after some time... Just to be sure. Thanks! You sad _one complicated ugly aggregation_, would you mind adding it to your answer? (I'm curious how that would look like)

Comment: I don't want to add it to the answer because on large results sets it would probably be prohibitively slow.  Image that first group stage aggregates all results into two arrays, both identical (scores) and now you $unwind one array, sort by those scores, limit to 10 and regroup to get top 10 (and you still have *all* scores in the other array).  Now you unwind *that* array and reverse sort and limit by it and group again. That gives you bottom 10.  Told you: ugly and impractical.