# Mysql Union query to MongoDB code

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am working on MongoDB code, I need to convert the following mysql code to MonogDB code

```
select sum(count) as total from table1 group by month 

UNION

select sum(quantity) as total from table2 group by month;
```

Please help. Thanks in advance!

Checked the above url.. But my question is slightly different from this..

I would like to get the sum of two different fields in two collections.

1. Field1 - count
2. Field2 - quantity

Example:

```
Table 1:

sno     count   month
1       20      3
2       50      5
3       70      7


Table 2:

sno     quantity    month
1       10          3
2       20          6
3       30          7
```

I want the results like below,

```
month   Total 
3       30
7       100
```

I want this result in single field. How can i do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MONGODB: Convert SQL Union query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22122328/mongodb-convert-sql-union-query)

Comment: Thanks for reply.. Added my explanation above.. can you please help..

Comment: You can probably use something like this to aggregate - `db.table1.aggregate([ {$group : {_id : "month", total : {$sum : $count}}}])` & `db.table1.aggregate([ {$group : {_id : "month", total : {$sum : $quantity}}}])`. Probably save the result into a new collection using `$out` & perform [`$setUnion`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setUnion/) similar to the Union in SQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I found solution with **MongoDB aggregation**.

```
db.getCollection('table1').aggregate([
    {$lookup : { from : "table2",localField : "month", foreignField :"month", as:"table2"}},
    {$unwind : "$table2"},
    {
        $group : {
            _id : {
                month :"$month",
            },
            total : { $sum : { $add: [ "$count", "$table2.quantity" ] }}            
        }
    },
    {$sort : {"_id.month":1}},
    {
        $project : {
            month :"$_id.month",
            total : 1,
            _id : 0
        }
    }
])
```

And below as my output which you expect.

```
{
    "total" : 30,
    "month" : 3
}
{
    "total" : 100,
    "month" : 7
}
```